# Can I create a custom interface to power views search?

Tags: 7, views

My content is well structured from an internal point of view, but I want to provide a more customer-focussed front-end to an advanced search form.

e.g. I want to offer a list of check boxes like

```
Show:
[ ] All
[X] Articles
[X] Yellow things
[ ] Super cheap things
```

I would then intercept this data and mangle it, so for example *Article* might become a parameter to `node_type` but *Yellow things* might be changed into `node_type = things AND field_colour = 'yellow'` while *Super cheap things* might be a different thing again.

i.e. I'd like to have a parameterised view set up but use my own customer-focussed forms, rather than use Views' own data-focussed exposed forms.

Is this straight forward?

(More info: I'm on Drupal 7.x. I'm very comfortable with PHP and SQL but I'm keen to do things the Drupal Way unless it's ridiculously inefficient)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a custom [views_handler_filter](http://views.doc.logrus.com/classviews__handler__filter.html). See [Views' API](http://views-help.doc.logrus.com/help/views/api) for a step by step introduction to implementing handler classes for Views.